# Extract values from a dict inside a list in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have this pandas column containing a dict inside a list:

```
1 []
2 [{'mal_id': 23, 'type': 'anime', 'name': 'Bandai Visual', 'url': 'https://myanimelist.net/anime/producer/23/Bandai_Visual'}, {'mal_id': 703, 'type': 'anime', 'name': 'Notes', 'url': 'https://myanimelist.net/anime/producer/703/Notes'}]
3 [{'mal_id': 1003, 'type': 'anime', 'name': 'Nippon Television Network', 'url': 'https://myanimelist.net/anime/producer/1003/Nippon_Television_Network'}]
```

I need to extract the name and store it in a column of list of names like so:

```
1 []
2 [Bandai Visual,Notes]
3 [Nippon Television Network]
```

I have tried:

```
df_trimmed['producer_name'] = df_trimmed['producers'].apply(lambda x: x[0]['name'] if x else None)

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I also have tried:

```
prods = df_trimmed['producers'].str[0].str['name']
prods

NaN
NaN
NaN
```

Another attempt:

```
def extract_names(row):
    names = []
    for producer in row:
        names.append(producer['name'])
    return names

df_trimmed['producer_names'] = df_trimmed['producers'].apply(extract_names)

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

As you can the first and third approaches return an error while the second approach returns null values. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit:
I mistakenly added " ". It is supposed to be a list and not a string. I have edited to mirror the actual data types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `col` the column of interest, you can use:

```
from ast import literal_eval

(df['col']
 #.apply(literal_eval) # uncomment if you have strings
 .explode()
 .str['name']
 .groupby(level=0)
 .agg(lambda x: list(x.dropna()))
 )
```

Output:

```
0                             []
1         [Bandai Visual, Notes]
2    [Nippon Television Network]
Name: col, dtype: object
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['[]', "[{'mal_id': 23, 'type': 'anime', 'name': 'Bandai Visual', 'url': 'https://myanimelist.net/anime/producer/23/Bandai_Visual'}, {'mal_id': 703, 'type': 'anime', 'name': 'Notes', 'url': 'https://myanimelist.net/anime/producer/703/Notes'}]", "[{'mal_id': 1003, 'type': 'anime', 'name': 'Nippon Television Network', 'url': 'https://myanimelist.net/anime/producer/1003/Nippon_Television_Network'}]"]})
```

Another approach using a list comprehension:

```
df['col'] = [[d['name'] for d in l
              if isinstance(d, dict)
              and 'name' in d]
             for l in df['col']]
```

Comment: This returns an error:
malformed node or string: array([{'mal_id': 23, 'name': 'Bandai Visual', 'type': 'anime', 'url': 'https://myanimelist.net/anime/producer/23/Bandai_Visual'}],
      dtype=object)

Comment: This means our input data is not a valid representation of a dictionary

Comment: Any suggestions on what should I do?

Comment: Can you update the example?

Comment: @mozway I think the values are valid lists and not string representations. So just removing `apply(literal_eval)` will work for OP.

Comment: @SomeDude the initial question showed quotes, but yes if the content is already python objects `.apply(literal_eval)` should be removed!

Answer (score 2):

Extract the needed attribute from a list of dicts:

```
df['col'].apply(lambda x: [d['name'] for d in x])
```

---

```
0                             []
1         [Bandai Visual, Notes]
2    [Nippon Television Network]
```

Comment: This also returns an error:
malformed node or string: array([{'mal_id': 23, 'name': 'Bandai Visual', 'type': 'anime', 'url': 'https://myanimelist.net/anime/producer/23/Bandai_Visual'}],
      dtype=object)

Comment: @mhutagalung, are you sure that you presented the original/actual data?

Comment: Apologise, I mistakenly added " " for every row making it a string. It is actually a list.